# Cosine similarity for multiple vectors

Tags: similarities, cosine-similarity

I am currently using cosine similarity to calculate the "similarity" of one vector to another. I am looking to extend this to situations where there are 3 or more vectors, specifically interested in capturing:

- the aggregate similarity/difference between a vector, and all other vectors.
- the overall similarity/diversity of the vectors

What are standard ways of doing this?